# OpenCart | Ошибка 500 в категориях и товарах

Tags: php, opencart

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, ошибка 500 на страницах категорий и товаров, на остальных страницах проблема не наблюдается, как быть, с чем может быть связана?

http://cd38421.tmweb.ru/

В логах множество таких ошибок:

Aug 12 11:47:03 bone012 apache_error: cd38421.tmweb.ru [Sat Aug 12 11:47:03 2017] [error] [pid 15721] sapi_apache2.c(325): [client
92.53.115.234:53536] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Table 'cd38421_generic.oc_genericshopbf_filter' doesn't exist
Error No: 1146
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE oc_genericshopbf_tmp_product (PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)) SELECT p.product_id, p.sort_order, "1" AS match_filters, (IF(MIN(ps.price) IS NOT NULL, MIN(ps.price), IF(MIN(pd2.price) IS NOT NULL, MIN(pd2.price), p.price))) AS actual_price FROM `oc_genericshopproduct` AS p INNER JOIN `oc_genericshopproduct_to_store` AS p2s ON (p2s.product_id = p.product_id) INNER JOIN `oc_genericshopbf_filter` AS f ON (p.product_id = f.product_id) INNER JOIN `oc_genericshopproduct_to_category` AS p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) LEFT JOIN `oc_genericshopproduct_discount` AS pd2 ON (pd2.product_id = p.product_id \n AND pd2.quantity = '1'\n AND (pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW())\n AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())\n AND pd2.customer_g in /home/c/cd38421/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 40

Comment: Ошибка 500 означает, что "произошла какая-то ошибка". Веб браузер не показывает, какая именно ошибка произошла. Нам нужно сообщение об ошибке PHP. Посмотрите логи ошибок PHP. Если их нет, то временно включите вывод ошибок в браузер.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh добавил то, что выводится в логах

Comment: Error: Table 'cd38421_generic.oc_genericshopbf_filter' doesn't exist   - Ошибка,таблица cd38421_generic.oc_genericshopbf_filter не существует. Потеряли таблицу БД,

Comment: А можно как то запуститься без неё?
Вообще странно что она пропала, в базу никто не лез...

Comment: Я вообще такой себе программист, мягко говоря...
Просто пытаюсь разобраться во всем этом и найти какое-то решение

Comment: Вряд ли. Лучше всего создать эту таблицу и создать правильно. Если вы не очень разбираетесь в программировании, то вам понадобится помощь специалиста по OpenCart. Увы это не я.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh понял, спасибо